# Chart js maximum number of legend

Tags: javascript, charts, max, legend

I want to know how to fix the maximum number of legend.

If this is not possible I would like to hide all legends

Thank you

My code .........................................................................................................................................

```
        var context = $('#withoutHangUpChart');

        var labels = [];
        var data = [];
        var backgroundColor = [];
        var hoverBackgroundColor = [];

        $.each(json, function (key, value) {
            labels.push(value.label);
            data.push(value.value);
            backgroundColor.push(value.color);
            hoverBackgroundColor.push(value.highlight);
        });

        // Simulation of many legends
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            labels.push(i + ' legend useless');
        }

        var data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                hoverBackgroundColor: hoverBackgroundColor
            }]
        };

        var options = {
                responsive: true
        };

        $.gWithoutHangUpChart = new Chart(context, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: data,
            options: options
        });
```

Comment: can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

in the current version of chartjs (2.6) you can get rid of the legend by changing your options to this.

```
var options = {
    responsive =true,
    legend: {
        display: false
    }
}
```